# How to transfer big Json object to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json, session

i have a search page that let the user choose a lot of criteria to search with and a lot of them are client side (created on fly) so i decided to save them in a Json object so i can catch all client data easily .

now i want to use these data to form a sql query so i can search with and display results in another page through a gird how to transfer it to another page with session or there is another suggestions to achieve that.

Comment: Query string ? ( although  there is a limitation...) or Cookie(s) -you can use 50 cookies per domain, and don't exceed 4095 bytes per domain. Im not saying its the best solution but it is a solution. p.s. you can also use sqlite db.

Comment: yeah and also i dont want it to appear to the user through url

Comment: Why don't simple post your big object to another page?

Comment: yeah i was thinking about that but i don't know how to do it with master and content page you know there is no form tag can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client data parameters (as JSON) and make an AJAX Request by posting the data and fetching the results on the same page instead of redirecting the user.

Comment: yeah this will be easy but it will not be suitable in my case because my search page is very large and if i did that it will be messy

Comment: In that case, does the user perform any action (button click). Trigger a POST request with the JSON Params (using form).

Comment: i am using master page so i dont have form tag so how to manage that?

Comment: Try checking this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178396/form-elements-in-asp-net-master-pages-and-content-pages

Comment: when i tried this an error appeared "A page can have only one server-side Form tag"