# Change form target in content area of a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webforms

We have an asp.net (2.5) application where we use one master page and a few hundred forms that utilize that master.  We're creating a new set of forms and we want to submit the form on a button so that we can use all of the form values on the next page.

However, the form tag is in our master page and asp.net seems to only allow 1 form tag per page.  Is there a way for me to change the target of the form post of the master from the child page or is there a way to add a second post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to access this second form from the code-behind on your new forms? If not there is a little hack you can do just add an end form tag and start a new tag that has the new target details

```
</form>
<form method="POST" action="blah.svc" >
  //non-asp.net form
```

However to change the actual postback url you would change the form action via the [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property on your buttons.

There is also Server.Transfer, kinda depends on what you are doing on your new forms.

Comment: WOW, can't believe it was that easy.  It seems a little kludgy on microsofts part that this is the only way to do this but I'll take it.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the target. In Masterpage add an id if it's not there already:

```
 <form runat="server" id="form1" >
```

Now in the content page access the form and change it's target:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlForm myForm = Page.Master.FindControl("form1") as HtmlForm;
    if (myForm != null)
    {

        myForm.Target = "_blank"; // _parent, _self or _top
    }
}
```

I don't know how much it will help.

You might look here, I found it very interesting: [Form Elements in ASP.NET Master Pages and Content Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240608/690329).